# Automatically generate shared library with function using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cython, ffi

I would like to embed numpy functions in C code and I have already managed to embed plain python functions that don't use external modules by using cython (and managed to put `import numpy...` at the top without actually using it), but when I use `np.array` in the function I run into a segfault on a line

`__Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_n_s_np); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)`

of the generated C source for that function. How can I make that work?

**foo.pyx:**

```
# cython: language_level=3
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cdef public int foo(int x):
    return np.array(range(x)).max()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(foo(5))
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <python3.7m/Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
extern int foo(int);
int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    printf("%d\n", foo(5));
    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation steps:**

```
cython --embed foo.pyx
gcc -g -o libfoo.so -fPIC -shared -pthread -I /usr/include/python3.7m foo.c -L /usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/ -Xlinker --export-dynamic -I /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -lpython3.7
gcc -g main.c -L. -lfoo -lpython3.7
```

Comment: Basically you need to initialize your module via `PyInit_foo` before it can be used.

Comment: @ead I've proposed a different duplicate which I think is better because it is the same error rather than a generic "how do I call Cython from C" question.